# I think I'm trying to pass data wrong in my variables? Novice coder inside

Tags: c++

I started learning some basics of C++ and I wanted to write some code to practices what I've learned. I wanted to make a class and some functions. It's supposed to be a title screen to start a text game, except there is no game...yet :P

Whenever I enter 1 to start so it displays "Good Work" it just does nothing after I hit enter.

Any point in the right direction would be great. I've been watching videos and reading tutorials on functions, it doesn't seem to cover the problem I'm having...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

//Function Protos
void keyError();
int userInput(int x);

//class library
class Title
{
    bool nSelect;
    int x;
public:
    void titleScreen()
    {
        while(nSelect)
        {
            cout << "Welcome to Biggs RPG!" << endl << "1. Play 2. Exit" << endl;
            userInput(x);
                if (userInput(1))
                    nSelect = 0;
                else if (userInput(2))
                {
                    cout << "Closing program..." <<endl;
                    nSelect = 0;
                }
                else
                    keyError();
         }
    }
};

int main()
{
Title displayTitle;
displayTitle.titleScreen();

cout << "Good work";
return 0;
}

void keyError()
{
cout << "Meow? Wrong input try again." << endl;
}   

int userInput(int x)
{
x = 0;
cin >> x;
return x;
}
```

Comment: I think what you were going for with `userInput` was `if (userInput() == 1)`

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the return value of userInput with 1 or 2, like this:

```
int userInput(void);

//class library
class Title
{
    bool nSelect;
    int x;
public:
    void titleScreen()
    {
        nSelect = true;
        while(nSelect)
        {
            cout << "Welcome to Biggs RPG!" << endl << "1. Play 2. Exit" << endl;
            x = userInput();
            if (x == 1)
                nSelect = false;
            else if (x == 2)
            {
                cout << "Closing program..." <<endl;
                nSelect = false;
            }
            else
                keyError();
         }
    }
};
```

and define userInput as:

```
int userInput(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: It gave me this when I tried it like that. error C2660: 'userInput' : function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: Did you also modified the declaration of "userInput" in the beginning of the program？    `int userInput(void); `The declaration and definition should always use the same type of argument.

Comment: It compiled but there is still logic errors. It's still taking the number and doing nothing with it. Thanks so much, I didn't get the (void) part, in the function or knew I could declare a variable with the function.

Comment: @user2442335 I just noticed that nSelect was defined as a `bool` type, but was assigned to 0. This is a bad style, it should be assigned to `ture` or `false`. And, since you didn't provide an explicit constructor, nSelect will be initialized to be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous stylistic and technical problems. Try learning from resources recommended in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/153285).

Here is a start…

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// "using namespace std;" is poor practice. Better to write out std::

/*  Unless you will have two title screens at the same time,
    this should probably be a namespace, not a "singleton" class. */
namespace Title
{
    int nSelect;

    void titleScreen()
    {
        do {
            // prompt for input
            std::cout << "Welcome to Biggs RPG!\n" "1. Play 2. Exit\n";

            // get ready to accept input, even if there was an error before
            if ( ! std::cin ) {
                std::cin.clear(); // tell iostream we're recovering from an error
                std::cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' ); // ignore error-causing input
            }
            // repeat if invalid input
         } while( ! std::cin >> nSelect || ! handleInput( nSelect ) );
```

The difference is that you want to ask for input, then handle it. The code you posted asks for input again each time it checks what the input *was*.

This is a `do … while` loop, so it executes at least once and then repeats as long as the condition *at the end* is true. If the user gives an invalid input, then `! std::cin` evaluates to `true`. Then the policy of C++ is to stop returning any input until you call `std::cin.clear()`, which signals that you are going to try again. `ignore` then gets rid of the invalid input. Then `! std::cin >> nSelect` tries to read a number, and if that operation is successful, call `handleInput` (which you must write) which should return `false` if the input was invalid. So if reading a number fails, or the wrong number was entered, the loop goes again.

Comment: Okay looks like I need to study a bit more. It was my first attempt at creating a piece of something I might be able to use or modify later. What you posted above went over my head a little bit ><

Comment: @user2442335 What part is over your head? I can clarify something. The code is just a rewrite of your prompt-for-input loop.

Comment: I haven't gone over namespaces yet, I heard briefly about singleton but I didn't get the scope of the context. I think it was just too advanced concept I couldn't visualize due to lack of experience.

Comment: 'std::cin.clear();
         } while( ! std::cin >> nSelect || ! handleInput( nSelect ) );'

Is what I really didn't get. I do know what a while loop is though :P XD

Comment: @user2442335 OK, I added more. You can look at http://cppreference.com to get info about anything in `std::` that you see in an answer.

Comment: Ok cool. I didn't know you could use cin and stuff in conditions.

! std::cin >> nSelect

This is saying if cin isn't nSelect? I just haven't seen cin used for anything else except simple things like asking it for numbers. I'll check that website out ASAP. Would up vote but it wouldn't let me :P

Comment: It means ask `cin` for a number, and then test for success or failure. (Remember that `cin >> x` returns `cin`. And `! cin` is `true` if there was a failure.)

Answer (score 0):

I sense confusion about the difference between parameters and return values. When you define a function as

```
int userInput(int x) {
  ...
```

You pass a value to the function (x) and **return** a value with the `return` statement. In your case you don't need to pass a parameter to your function; you need to return a value. You access this value by assigning it to another variable:

```
theResult = userInput(123);
```

But it doesn't matter what value you pass to the function; you might as well use

```
int userInput(void) {
  ...
```

In which case you can use

```
theResult = userInput();
```

Now just to confuse you, it is possible to pass the *address* of a variable as a parameter to a function. You can use that either to access data (usually a "larger" block of data like an array or struct) but it can also be used to provide a place where a return value is stored. Thus

```
void squareMe(int *x){
    *x*=*x;
}
```

Would return the square of the number pointed to in that location. You could then do

```
int x=4;
squareMe(&x);
cout << x;
```

Would print out 16 (!). This is because the function looks at the contents of the address (&x is the address of the variable x), and multiplies it by itself in- place.

I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: It seems like changing it to a (void) still has the issue of 1 or 2 not being accepted. I never knew a title screen was going to be such a difficult first task!